# How can I search for two terms in Hibernate Search and get them both in result?

Tags: hibernate, full-text-search, hibernate-search

Is there some way to find results in Hibernate Search with all searched terms ? What I mean is that, for instance, I  search for a given term like "house" and I got a list of "Houses". However, if I'd want go refine my search and look for "house" and "pool", I'd like to get a list of "house" AND "pool" and not a list of "house" OR "pool". 
I'm not sure I'm clear enough. So, basically, what I need is to perform a search with more than one word and the search must consider them all, not only one. 
Is that possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set default operator to AND using QueryParser:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "yourfield",standardAnalyzer);     
// query terms should ANDed by default
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.AND);
Query luceneQuery = queryParser.parse("house pool");
// turn it into an hibernate search query
org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery hibQuery =
session.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, YourClass.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you want,Assuming you have an String array of terms to be searched.

```
BooleanQuery finalLuceneQuery=new BooleanQuery();
for(String term:terms)
{
  TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("your search field", term));

  finalLuceneQuery.add(query,BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery, <your class>.class);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

When searching on several fields it is possible to specify terms that MUST, SHOULD or MUST_NOT appear in each field. The following code is based on Lucene 4.10.3.

```
// fields we are interested in
String[] fields = {"description", "content"};
// terms SHOULD appear in description OR MUST appear in content
BooleanClause.Occur[] flags = {BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST};
// besides the StandardAnalyzer there are analysers for many languages like
// FrenchAnalyser, RussianAnalyser and so on
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
// create a multi field query using parse static method
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = 
    MultiFieldQueryParser.parse("house pool", fields, flags, analyzer);
// convert to Hibernate query
org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery hibQuery =
    session.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, YourClass.class);
```

If using JPA you will need to convert it to a JPA query:

```
// get an EntityManager from your EntityManagerFactory (emf)
javax.persistence.EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
// Convert it to a FullTextEntityManager
org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager ftem =
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
// convert it to a JPA query
javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
    ftem.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, YourClass.class);
```

Yet another way of getting the Lucene query (maybe simpler?):

```
// fields we are interested in
String[] fields = {"description", "content"};
// besides the StandardAnalyzer there are analysers for many languages like
// FrenchAnalyser, RussianAnalyser and so on
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
// to set MUST for all fields we need an instance of the parser
MultiFieldQueryParser mfqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
mfqp.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = mfqp.parse("house pool");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using any `Analyzer` here coz Hibernate implicitly uses `StandardAnalyzer` which will split the words based on `white spaces` so the solution here is set the `Analyze` to `NO` on the field it will automatically performs `Multi Phrase Search`

```
@Column(name="skill")
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
@Analyzer(definition="SkillsAnalyzer")
private String skill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key word MUST during query building.  Hibernate Search also supports combining queries using various strategies:

-SHOULD: the query should contain the matching elements of the subquery

-MUST: the query must contain the matching elements of the subquery

-MUST NOT: the query must not contain the matching elements of the subquery

The aggregations are similar to the boolean ones AND, OR and NOT.

```
    Query combinedQuery = queryBuilder
   .bool()

   .must(queryBuilder.phrase()
   .onField("productName).sentence("samsung galaxy s8")
   .createQuery())

   .must(queryBuilder.keyword()
   .onField("productCategory").matching("smartphone")
   .createQuery())

   .createQuery();


    // wrap Lucene query in an Hibernate Query object
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(combinedQuery, Product.class);

    // execute search and return results (sorted by relevance as default)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Product> results = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

This reference is obtained from the link http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search