# How to filter a search query on multiple fields?

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I have a list of studies. And I want to search over them with a typeahead function in a front page.
For that I use Hibernate Search with Spring Boot (2.1.5).
I indexed my STUDY table and some fields are marked with `@Field` attribute to be indexed.

The search works well.
But now I want to add a filter to use the same typeahead function but searching of a subset of my studies.

For that I created a filter like the Hibernate Search documentation but I didn't found a way to filter on two field with a OR between them.

My actual filter but filtering only on one field (`avisDefinitifCet`):

```
/**
 * etudeFilter
 */
public class EtudeFilterFactory {
    private String clasCet1ErPassage;
    private String avisDefinitifCet;

    public void setClasCet1ErPassage(String clasCet1ErPassage) {
        this.clasCet1ErPassage = clasCet1ErPassage;
    }

    public void setAvisDefinitifCet(String avisDefinitifCet) {
        this.avisDefinitifCet = avisDefinitifCet;
    }

    @Factory
    public Query getFilter() {
        System.out.println("Filter avisDefinitifCet : " + this.avisDefinitifCet.toLowerCase());
        return new TermQuery(new Term("avisDefinitifCet", this.avisDefinitifCet.toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

How can I filter with a second field in my case `clasCet1ErPassage`?

At this end make a search on the standard search query and applying the filter like this

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDY
WHERE 
A=t OR B=t OR C=t -- Normal search
AND (avisDefinitifCet='acceptation' OR clasCet1ErPassage='acceptation') -- Filter on two fields
```

My search function:

```
public List<Etude> search(String text, Map<String, String> allParams) {
        text = stripAccents(text);
        // get the full text entity manager
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

        // create the query using Hibernate Search query DSL
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager
                .getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(Etude.class)
                .get();

        // Simple Query String queries
        Query query = queryBuilder
                .simpleQueryString()
                .onFields("n0Cet")
                .andField("anneeCet")
                .andField("noDansAnneeCet")
                .andField("sigleEtude")
                .andField("titreEtude")
                .andField("traitement1")
                .andField("traitement2")
                .andField("traitement3")
                .andField("traitement4")
                .andField("traitement5")
                .andField("demandeurIgr.nomInvestigateurIgr")
                .andField("investigateurHorsIgr.nomInvestigateur")
                .andField("investigateurIgr.nomInvestigateurIgr")
                .andField("promoteur.nomPromoteur")
                .matching(text)
                .createQuery();

        // wrap Lucene query in an Hibernate Query object
        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager
                .createFullTextQuery(query, Etude.class)
                .setMaxResults(101);

        // Here allParams contains
        // avisDefinitifCet => 'acceptation',
        // clasCet1ErPassage => 'acceptation'
        allParams.forEach((key, value) -> {
            fullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter("etudeFilter").setParameter(key, value);
        });

        return (List<Etude>) fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
```

Am I thinking in the right way to implement it or I'm going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search for two terms in Hibernate Search and get them both in result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422512/how-can-i-search-for-two-terms-in-hibernate-search-and-get-them-both-in-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Appparently you're using full-text filters, where you indeed have to use Lucene APIs directly.

In this case, just use a boolean junction with "should" clauses. When there's only "should" clauses in a boolean junction, at least one of them has to match.

```java
    @Factory
    public Query getFilter() {
        String valueToMatch = this.avisDefinitifCet.toLowerCase();
        return new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(new TermQuery(new Term("avisDefinitifCet", valueToMatch)), Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(new TermQuery(new Term("clasCet1ErPassage", valueToMatch)), Occur.SHOULD)
            .build();
    }
```

---

Previous answer:

If you're new to Lucene, you really should give the [Hibernate Search DSL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query) a try.

In your case, you'll want a [keyword query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_keyword_queries) that targets two fields:

```
EntityManager em = ...;

FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( Etude.class ).get();

Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
    .onField("avisDefinitifCet").andField("clasCet1ErPassage")
    .matching("acceptation")
    .createQuery();
```

Note that, despite the method being called `andField`, it's actually an "OR": the query will match if any field matches.

For more advanced combination of queries, have a look at [boolean junctions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_combining_queries).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to use the filter mechanism to filtering the query results. I also tried with boolean junction but I can't make it work like I want. I updated my question with the search function I'm using.

Comment: thank you very much! It's works like I expected. So great :)

Answer (score 0):

Here what I used to solve my problem thanks to @yrodiere

```
@Factory
    public Query getFilter() {
        return new BooleanQuery.Builder()
                .add(new TermQuery(new Term("avisDefinitifCet", this.avisDefinitifCet.toLowerCase())), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
                .add(new TermQuery(new Term("clasCet1ErPassage", this.clasCet1ErPassage.toLowerCase())), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
                .build();
    }
```